# This function can get p-value from which statistics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, z-statistic

I know that I can get p-value from z-statistic (called zval here) using following function (Python):

```
pval = 2*(scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(zval)))
```

or with:

```
pval = 2*(1 - scipy.stats.norm.cdf(abs(z)))
```

Where `sf` is survival function and `cdf` is Cumulative distribution function. Documentation of theses are [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

However, I am not clear that above method can be used for which other statistics. For example, can above be used for `t-statistic` in Student's t-test?

Some theory behind above concept will be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed. While it does depart from code, it clearly asks about theoretical development, which I think is firmly on topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To construct a level $\alpha$ rejection region we first calculate the level $\alpha$ critical value $c_\alpha$. For a two-tailed
test based on a test statistic that is $N(0,1)$ under $H_0$, the critical value is defined implicitly by
\begin{equation}\label{deficritval}\tag{1}
1-\alpha/2=\Phi(c_\alpha)
\end{equation}
where $\Phi$ denotes the standard normal CDF. Hence,
$$
\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)=c_\alpha
$$
where $\Phi^{-1}$ denotes the quantile function.

The probability that $z > c_\alpha$ is $1 - (1 -\alpha/2) = \alpha/2$, and likewise, $P(z < -c_\alpha)=\alpha/2$, by symmetry. Thus, $P(|z| > c_\alpha)=\alpha$, as desired. For example, when $\alpha = 0.05$, $\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)= 1.96$.

The $p$-value is defined as the smallest level for which a test based on an obersved statistic $\hat{z}$ rejects.

For a two-tailed test,
$$
p(\hat{z}) = 2(1- \Phi(|\hat{z}|))
$$
To see this, note that the test based on $\hat{z}$ rejects if
$$|\hat{z}| > c_\alpha$$
This is equivalent to
$$\Phi(|\hat{z}|) > \Phi(c_\alpha),$$
because $\Phi$ is strictly increasing.
Further, from eq. \eqref{deficritval}
$$
\Phi(c_\alpha)=1-\alpha/2
$$
The smallest value of $\alpha$ for which the inequality holds is thus obtained by solving the equation
$$\Phi(|\hat{z}|) = 1-\alpha/2$$
for $\alpha$, which gives $2(1- \Phi(|\hat{z}|))$.

Hence, we require that the test statistic be $N(0,1)$ under the null and that we reject for both very negative and very positive values of the test statistic (i.e., conduct a two-tailed test).

Whether the result applies to Student's t-test therefore depends on the null distribution you entertain. If you can make a normality assumption on the data (see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117406/proof-that-the-coefficients-in-an-ols-model-follow-a-t-distribution-with-n-k-d) to what that refers more precisely in a regression context) to which you apply the test, it is well known that the t-statistic follows a t-distribution. Hence, you would need to replace $\Phi$ with the corresponding c.d.f. of the t-distribution.

On the other hand, even without a normality assumption, the t-statistic will usually be normally distributed in large samples thanks to a central limit theorem. See e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348972/are-there-any-examples-of-where-the-central-limit-theorem-does-not-hold).