# Central Limit Theorem for t(2)-distributed random variables

Tags: probability, convergence, central-limit-theorem, t-distribution

Let $X_k \overset{iid}{\sim} t(2)$. Is there any limit theorem about $\bar{X}$?

I know $\text{Var}(\bar{X})$ doesn't exist, so I cannot use classical CLT. But I believe there must be other means to study it.

I got this question when I was thinking about how quickly it converges to zero in probability.

Comment: To my recollection I have seen a limit theorem involving $f(n)\cdot(\bar{X}-\mu)$ for it. I may not recall all the details correctly but $f(n)$ would have been different from $\sqrt{n}$ (there may have been a log in $f$). I think the convergence was to a zero mean normal. Sorry that's not much to go on.

Comment: Wow, that's very helpful! Thanks a lot! I guess your intuition is correct --- its covergence rate may be $O(\sqrt{n}/log(n))$. I did some simulations and I found the limiting distribution is approximately normal. And I also find very helpful results [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348972). I guess its useful to talk about random variables whose tails decrease as $|x|^{\frac{1}{3}}$ (because it has the same order as the tail of t(2)), like the results mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#A_generalized_central_limit_theorem).

Comment: Yep, that looks something like like what I was half-remembering from ... a good few decades back. Naturally when tails are very heavy (enough that variance is not finite for the $X_i$'s, so for the scaled average it won't be finite at any given $n$), such convergence must be extremely "slow".